# Model Binding ajax request in .Net Core

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

In my project I'm making an ajax request like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var friends = [];
    friends[0] = { Id: 1, Name: "John" };
    friends[1] = { Id: 2, Name: "Mike" };

    var obj =  {
        Id: 1,
        Name: "Piotr",
        Friends: friends
    }

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Home/Test',
        data: obj
    });

});
```

I'm trying to bind the data to classes below:

```
public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
}

public class Friend
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In action result like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test(Person p)
    {
        HttpRequest r = HttpContext.Request;

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = "",
            iTotalRecords = 2,
            iTotalDisplayRecords = 2,
            aaData = ""
        });
    }
```

The problem is that the request is triggering Test action result but with blank Freiends list. Data is not bound to Friends property of Person class.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rz58.png)

What am I doing wrong?

The request querystring is like this:
`{?Id=1&Name=Piotr&Friends%5B0%5D%5BId%5D=1&Friends%5B0%5D%5BName%5D=John&Friends%5B1%5D%5BId%5D=2&Friends%5B1%5D%5BName%5D=Mike}`

Comment: Why do you do it with HttpGet. try HttpPost.

Comment: when i'm changing it to post all Person p properties are null or 0;.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a couple of things to get this to work.

**Javascript**:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var friends = [];
    friends[0] = { id: 1, name: "John" };
    friends[1] = { id: 2, name: "Mike" };

    var obj =  {
        id: 1,
        name: "Piotr",
        friends: friends
    }

    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "application/json",
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/Test',
        //convert your data to a JSON object before you send it
        data: JSON.stringify( obj)
    });

});
```

**ASPNET Core**: The `[FromBody]` attribute configures the correct input formatter to parse the obj sent. In case of JSON, ASPNET Core will configure the input formatter using Json.NET library.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test([FromBody]Person p)
{

    return Json(new
    {
        sEcho = "",
        iTotalRecords = 2,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = 2,
        aaData = ""
    });
}
```